# How to get the cluster IP of a kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I've created a service which wraps an nfs, and I need to get the cluster IP for it so that I can set it to persistent volumne using it.

I know I can use the following to get this:

```
$ kubectl get svc nfs-server
NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
nfs-server   ClusterIP   10.59.243.58   <none>        2049/TCP,20048/TCP,111/TCP   2m
```

What I want to know is, how do I extract that cluster IP in a bash script?  It's generated as part of a deployment process, so I can't just type it in to my persistent volume manifest.

Answer (score 6):

You can parse the of `kubectl get svc` command something like below to get the inner details of the deployment.

```
export CLUSTER_IP=$(kubectl get services/nfs-server -o go-template='{{(index.spec.clusterIP)}}');echo CLUSTER_IP=$CLUSTER_IP
```

Alternatively, you can try any combination of shell hacks involving `cut and awk`. One such example is;

```
kubectl describe svc/nfs-server | grep IP: | awk '{print $2;}'
```

Comment: The export CLUSTER_IP command gave me `error: error executing template "{{(index.spec.clusterIP)}}": template: output:1:3: executing "output" at <index>: wrong number of args for index: want at least 1 got 0`. Second command works though

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer using `go-template` output was failing. Using `jsonpath` worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

cluster_ip=$(kubectl get svc nfs-server -ojsonpath='{.spec.clusterIP}')
echo $cluster_ip
```